# Is there any thing like apply lem in *?

Tags: coq

Is there any way to call `apply lem in H` for every possible H in premises, like `rewrite lem in *`?

```
Axiom P Q : nat -> Prop.
Axiom lem : forall (n : nat), P n -> Q n.
Goal P O -> P (S O) -> True.
  intros. apply lem in H. apply lem in H0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything built in, but it's possible to write such a tactic with Ltac.

First, the special case.

```
Axiom P Q : nat -> Prop.
Axiom lem : forall (n : nat), P n -> Q n.
Goal P O -> P (S O) -> True.
  intros.
  repeat match goal with
    x : _ |- _ => apply lem in x
  end.
Abort.
```

Now we can generalize this

```
Ltac apply_in_premises t :=
  repeat match goal with
    x : _ |- _ => apply t in x
  end.
```

and use it like this:

```
Goal P O -> P (S O) -> True.
  intros.
  apply_in_premises lem.
Abort.
```

Unfortunately, this way of doing it can cause an infinite loop if applying `lem` produces something else that `lem` can be applied to.

```
Axiom P : nat -> Prop.
Axiom lem : forall (n : nat), P n -> P (S n).
Ltac apply_in_premises t :=
  repeat match goal with
    x : _ |- _ => apply t in x
  end.

Goal P O -> P (S O) -> nat -> True.
  intros.
  apply_in_premises lem. (* infinite loop *)
Abort.
```

If this is a concern for you, you can use a variant suggested by Yves in the comments. Simply changing `apply t in x` to `apply t in x; revert x` will ensure that that hypothesis won't be matched again. However, the end result will have all the hypotheses in the goal, like `P -> G`, instead of `p: P` as a premise and `G` as the goal.

To automatically re`intro`duce these hypotheses, we can keep track of how many times a hypothesis was reverted, then introduce them again.

```
Ltac intro_n n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => idtac
  | S ?n' => intro; intro_n n'
  end.

Ltac apply_in_premises_n t n :=
  match goal with
  | x : _ |- _ => apply t in x; revert x;
                  apply_in_premises_n t (S n)
  | _ => intro_n n (* now intro all the premises that were reverted *)
  end.

Tactic Notation "apply_in_premises" uconstr(t) := apply_in_premises_n t 0.

Axiom P : nat -> Prop.
Axiom lem : forall (n : nat), P n -> P (S n).

Goal P O -> P (S O) -> nat -> True.
  intros.
  apply_in_premises lem. (* only applies `lem` once in each of the premises *)
Abort.
```

Here, the tactic `intro_n n` applies `intro` `n` times.

I haven't tested this in general, but it works well in the case above. It might fail if a hypothesis can't be reverted (for example, if some other hypothesis depends on it). It also may reorder the hypotheses, since when a reverted hypothesis is reintroduced, it's put on the end of the hypothesis list.

Comment: Did you try `apply t in x; revert x`.  In the end, you goal will contain all the newly created hypotheses.  This is not perfect, but it should avoid a looping behavior.

Comment: @Yves That worked pretty well. I've found a way to make sure to `intro` all the hypotheses again and I'll edit it in when I get the time later. Thanks!